# Which CSS definition is stopping the left sidebar DIV from growing in height?

Tags: html, css

I am having a problem determining which CSS class definition is stopping the left sidebar (the one with the pinkish background) from growing in height on [this page](http://princecorp.dev.warp9inc.com/testing.html).

I should have mentioned previously that I have tried everything I can think of and researched many questions on here, including adding `height:auto;` and `overflow:auto;` to `col-left`, `sidebar`, `col-main` and all others already.

Can someone help me identify it?

Comment: Create a simplified example of the problem you're having the post it on jsfiddle. I don't even see a sidebar in the link you posted...

Comment: @bookcasey It is a dithered-pink sidebar on the left, I just double-checked the link I posted.  I will create a jsfiddle now, thanks!\

Comment: A screenshot or two with the relevant part of the page highlighted, and a description of what it should be doing differently, would also be helpful.

Comment: Thanks guys, one second and I will update!

Comment: I still have yet to see any sign of a sidebar, in IE, Firefox, or Chrome, dithered-pink or otherwise. Does the sidebar only appear if you're logged into the site? Bear in mind, what I see at the URL you initially posted is a login page.

Comment: I just created a static page for assistance and uploaded it.  The link is in the question and  http://princecorp.dev.warp9inc.com/testing.html here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At a glance, I think the main problem is the use of `position:absolute` for `.col-left`. `position:absolute` causes that element to be outside of the flow of the rest of the page. The height of it has no effect on the resulting height of its parent (as if it were not inside the parent).

Comment: You are awesome Matt, thanks for your patience - this was my first question ever asked here!

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the page source, the height of the  element is not specified via CSS. If you would like the sidebar to grow, you would need to specify a height and/or min/max-height properties.

Answer (score 0):

You have a lot of height values set to 100%, it took me going all the way to the page div class before I was able to increase the vertical real estate of your content.

I recommend evaluating whether you should be using that particular height property in so many elements, you may be constraining yourself with no reason.

Comment: Yes, I tested each one individually and it is the package Magento root CSS I am working with.